# Autofac filter resolved IEnumerable implementations

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, autofac

Is it possible to filter dependencies when resolving `IEnumerable` in autofac?

I have multiple implementations of an interface (`IHandler` in the example below) which are defined & registered using an Autofac module in isolated projects. I would like to be able to filter the implementations when resolving in the parent type (`Processor` in the example below).

*The `IHandler` implementations could be injected into the `Processor` and filtered in the `ctor` but this would require resolving all implementations regardless whether they are required which is wasteful.*

```
public interface IHandler { }
public class Handler1 : IHandler { }
public class Handler2 : IHandler { }
public class Handler3 : IHandler { }

public class Processor {
    public IEnumerable<IHandler> Handlers;

    public Processor(IEnumerable<IHandler> handlers) {
        Handlers = handlers;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.RegisterType<Handler1>().As<IHandler>();
    builder.RegisterType<Handler2>().As<IHandler>();
    builder.RegisterType<Handler3>().As<IHandler>();

    builder.RegisterType<Processor>().AsSelf();

    var container = builder.Build();

    var processor = container.Resolve<Processor>();
}
```

As only 1 key can be resolved at a time, my attempt with keys didnt work:

```
[Flags]
public enum HandlerType
{
    One = 1,
    Two = 2,
    Three = 4
}

builder.RegisterType<Handler1>().Keyed<IHandler>(HandlerType.One);
builder.RegisterType<Handler2>().Keyed<IHandler>(HandlerType.Two);
builder.RegisterType<Handler3>().Keyed<IHandler>(HandlerType.Three);

var enabledHandlers = HandlerType.One | HandlerType.Three;
builder.RegisterType<Processor>().AsSelf()
    .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForKeyed<IEnumerable<IHandler>>(enabledHandlers));
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html

Comment: Based on which condition(s) do you wish to filter those handlers?

Comment: Thanks @UmutOzel, I may be able to make it work using a `ResolvedParameter`.

Comment: @Steven I should have made it more clear, from a configuration file e.g. `<add key="Handlers" value="1,3" />`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can provide proper filter during container set up phase (as you do in your sample code), you could change your `Processor` type registration to the following:

```
builder.RegisterType<Processor>().AsSelf()
    .WithParameter((p, c) => p.Name == "handlers",
        (p, c) => new[] 
            {
                c.ResolveKeyed<IHandler>(HandlerType.One),
                c.ResolveKeyed<IHandler>(HandlerType.Three)
            });
```

Values you need to use could be taken from anywhere you want, from config file too.

Comment: This is close to the solution I used but with filtering on the resolved classes based on the configuration... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the `Meta<T>` and `Lazy<T>` [implicit relationship types](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html) to allow the processor to read config and control all that at runtime. That would also allow you to filter differently in different conditions or turn filtering off entirely without having to change any keys.

Register the handlers with metadata instead of as keyed services...

```
builder.RegisterType<Handler1>()
       .As<IHandler>()
       .WithMetadata("type", HandlerType.One);
builder.RegisterType<Handler2>()
       .As<IHandler>()
       .WithMetadata("type", HandlerType.Two);
builder.RegisterType<Handler3>()
       .As<IHandler>()
       .WithMetadata("type", HandlerType.Three);
```

Update your processor to take `IEnumerable<Meta<Lazy<IHandler>>>` and filter during construction or at some later point when the handlers are needed, your call.

```
public class Processor
{
  private readonly IHandler[] _handlers;
  public Processor(IEnumerable<Meta<Lazy<IHandler>>> handlers)
  {
    this._handlers =
      handlers
        .Where(h => h.Metadata["type"] == HandlerType.One || h.Metadata["type"] == HandlerType.Three)
        .Select(h => h.Value.Value)
        .ToArray();
  }
}
```

Each item coming in to the constructor will be a `Meta<Lazy<IHandler>>`:

- `Meta<T>` has a `Metadata` dictionary to query and the `Value` will be the `Lazy<IHandler>`.
- `Lazy<T>` will not resolve/construct the handler until you call the `Value` property, so it won't be expensive or cause resolutions you don't want.

So `item.Value.Value` will be the resolved `IHandler` (as you see in the LINQ above).

The stuff in the `Where` filter could be based on config or anything else. But the real win here is that if you still need to resolve all the handlers somewhere else...

```
public OtherHandlerConsumer(IEnumerable<IHandler> handlers)
```

...that will still work. You can't do that if they're all keyed. Plus you can add as much metadata as you want to the registrations or even define more robust [strongly typed metadata](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/metadata.html) so you can make smarter decisions about which handlers you want.

Comment: Very interesting approach, I hadn't considered `Lazy` to alleviate the cost of resolving dependencies that may not be used.

Answer (score 0):

Since the registered handlers are based on a configuration switch, it means that the selected handlers won't change at runtime. This is very different than selecting the handlers based on some *runtime* condition. I therefore propose something similar to this:

```
var handlerIds = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Handlers"].Split(',');

if (handlerIds.Contains("1")) builder.RegisterType<Handler1>().As<IHandler>();
if (handlerIds.Contains("2")) builder.RegisterType<Handler2>().As<IHandler>();
if (handlerIds.Contains("3")) builder.RegisterType<Handler3>().As<IHandler>();
if (handlerIds.Contains("4")) builder.RegisterType<Handler4>().As<IHandler>();
// etc

builder.RegisterType<Processor>().AsSelf();
```

Comment: This may work for some but in my case the `handler`s are "defined & registered using an Autofac module in isolated projects" meaning they are independent of of configuration etc.

Comment: I'm confused. In an earlier comment you deacribed they came from the configuration.

Comment: Yes the config of, in the example, which `IHandler` to use is a config file. But each `IHandler` impl is a separate project with minimal deps and self registering AutofacModule. Sorry I should have been more clear about that.

Comment: With that explanation, that doesn"t really change my answer, except that each if check os moved into a module. You still don't need keyed registrations, lazy or meta.